# What's another way to say "to become"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests, synonyms

As in this simple example:

> I want to become a firefighter.

Now, you *could* replace "become" with "be", but that technically changes the meaning.

I found synonyms on [collinsdictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/become) listed below, but they don't seem to work in my example.

> "come to be, develop into, be transformed into, grow into, change
>   into, evolve into, alter to, mature into, metamorphose into, ripen
>   into"

Comment: You think that's bad, try finding a synonym for "be".

Comment: *"but they don't seem to work in my example."* Why not?

Comment: Just try..."I want to evolve in a firefighter" or "I want to transform into a firefighter" LOL

Comment: If you want to evolve in a firefighter that would suggest you're some sort of internal parasite.  Evolving *into* a firefighter, on the other hand ...

Answer (score 2):

Also specific to example:

"be employed as"
"get a job as"
"pursue a career as"
"get work as"
"work as"
"be hired as"
"enter the [...] field"
"enter the [...] profession"

Answer (score 1):

Well specific to the example, perhaps you could take either of these routes.

*I **aspire to be** a firefighter.*

*I am an **aspiring** firefighter.*

Those do anything for you?